# C++ Error STATUS_ACCESS_VIOLATION

Tags: c++

I'm getting that error by running this simplest code:

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "stdlib.h"

int main()
{
    FILE* in;
    FILE* out;

    in = fopen("foo.in", "r");
    out = fopen("bar.out", "w+");

    int something;
    fscanf(in, "%i", something);
    fprintf(out, "%i", something);

    fclose(in);
    fclose(out);
    return 0;
}
```

I'm running it out of Sublime Text 3.

Comment: You should check that your files were opened successfully.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`fscanf` expects a pointer, meaning that it modify the value of `something` while in the function `fscanf` if you send it by copy the value will be correct while in scope (i.e. while in `fscanf`) but the result is never returned so your copy of `something` is never changes, (i.e. it's still not initialized).

so what you need to do:

```
int something;
fscanf(in, "%i", &something);
fprintf(out, "%i", something);
```

and it should work, if you are trying to read an integer from `foo.in` and write it to `bar.out`.